# Overriden method can call on inherited private getter, but not inherited private setters

Tags: scala, inheritance, private

I think this could apply to both Java and Scala, but - a week in to learning Scala so trying that out. I have this:

```
class myBaseClass {

  private var member: Int = 100

  def doStuff(): Unit ={
    checkMember()
    alterMember(5)
  }

  private[this] def checkMember(): Unit = {
  //throws exception if member < 0
  }

  private[this] def alterMember(i : Int): Unit = {
    member -= i
  }

}
```

And then I have a class which inherits the lot, overriding just one method as to call `alterMember` with a different value:

```
class mySubClass extends myBaseClass {

  override def doStuff(): Unit ={
        checkMember() // gives compiler error
        alterMember(10) // gives compiler error AND IntelliJ says "alterMember inaccessible from this place"
   }
}
```

`checkMember()` and `alterMember` are acting like private getters and setters. (I do only want `doStuff` to be able to change `member` , and are both inherited. WRONG - IGNORE THIS I don't understand why `mySubClass` is clearly able to access the private member as `checkMember` is just fine, but it seems it cannot alter it. Why would there be this variance? IGNORE UP TO HERE

Erasing the `[this]` makes no difference, but making `alterMember` public "fixes" it - but gives a level of access to `member` that I do not want.

Comment: Please post your *actual*, compiling code which reproduces the problem - the code you posted above contains syntax errors, for example you forgot `def` in front of `checkMember` and `alterMember` in class `myBaseClass` and `=` between `Unit` and `{`.

Comment: I don't know how you make `checkMember()` compile but i have "inaccessible from this place" on both methods. I would suggest to use `protected`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors, fixed them. My original code won't compile - and contains a little more verbosity and specifics to other classes which may obscure the specific concept I'm going after.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your fixed code. In the Scala 2.12 REPL the calls to both methods give "error: not found: value <methodname>".

Comment: Hmm... With the compilation it gives me `error: not found:` with both methods. But IntelliJ only complains (when editing) about the latter.

Comment: Probably a bug in the IntelliJ Scala plug-in.

Comment: The actual compiler will find more errors than the plugin. Also, if the class does not compile for other reasons, you may not get complete reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here, based on @MuratMustafin 's suggestion is to make the `member` and the two private methods protected.

What was also throwing, was that I needed to compile  `myBaseClass` before attempting to compile `mySubClass` , otherwise it will say `mySubClass` cannot find those protected methods. Perhaps it's something with the Scala compiler that differs from the Java compiler in that it won't automatically know to compile them all, or compile them in order.